# How to add rule to nftables.conf

Tags: nftables

In my terminal, I write :

`sudo nft add table inet f2b-table`

`systemctl reload nftables.service`

then :

`sudo nft list ruleset`

result in the terminal (ok) :

`table inet f2b-table { }`

But when i open nftables.conf, why table inet f2b not appearing

why it displays the table in the terminal and not in the nftables.conf (is it two different files?)

What should be done to update the nftables.conf?

Answer (score 0):

You have updated the tables in the kernel (not a file).
If you update the file, then it will be in the file.
If you then tell nft to re-read the file, then it will be copied to the kernel.

All Unix configuration files, are just files. At some point they are read and loaded into the kernel, or program that they are configuring. `nftables.conf` will be loaded when the system starts, and most likely when you re-start `nft`, or tell it to re-load its configuration.

There is probably a way to get the kernel to dump the data that could be copied to the file. However, this will also include data that was already present before the change.

Answer (score 0):

When I looked at the nftables wiki, I found only this page that deals with loading tables from a file:  https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Scripting

The page describes how the `nft -f filename` command will load table configuration from a file, but there is no matching command to save configuration to a file.

There's brief mention that the output from the "nft list" commands is one of the acceptable syntaxes for the file.  This implies that `nft list ruleset > filename` would create a file that can be read by "nft -f"

Why didn't the `systemctl reload nftables.service` command do this?  Apparently the systemctl configuration created by the package maintainer doesn't perform the save-to-file action.  Perhaps it only performs the read-from-file action.  I don't have more detailed info because I don't have a computer with NFT packet filtering and you didn't mention which Linux/Unix you're working with.

Comment: The proper command to dump nftables rules is `list ruleset`, not `list tables`.

Comment: Thanks @artem-s-tashkinov.  I saw the wiki description _nft -f <filename> accepts 2 formats, the first is the format seen in the output of nft list table._ and imitated the command given.  I've fixed my post now.